# Java find nearest (or equal) value in collection

Tags: java, collections, find, predicate

I have a class along the lines of:

```
public class Observation {
   private String time;
   private double x;
   private double y;

   //Constructors + Setters + Getters
}
```

I can choose to store these objects in any type of collection (Standard class or 3rd party like Guava). I have stored some example data in an ArrayList below, but like I said I am open to any other type of collection that will do the trick. So, some example data:

```
ArrayList<Observation> ol = new ArrayList<Observation>();
ol.add(new Observation("08:01:23",2.87,3.23));
ol.add(new Observation("08:01:27",2.96,3.17));
ol.add(new Observation("08:01:27",2.93,3.20));
ol.add(new Observation("08:01:28",2.93,3.21));
ol.add(new Observation("08:01:30",2.91,3.23));
```

The example assumes a matching constructor in `Observation`. The timestamps are stored as `String` objects as I receive them as such from an external source but I am happy to convert them into something else. I receive the observations in chronological order so I can create and rely on a sorted collection of observations. The timestamps are NOT unique (as can be seen in the example data) so I cannot create a unique key based on `time`.

Now to the problem. I frequently need to find one (1) observation with a `time` equal or nearest to a certain time, e.g if my time was `08:01:29` I would like to fetch the 4th observation in the example data and if the time is `08:01:27` I want the 3rd observation.

I can obviously iterate through the collection until I find the time that I am looking for, but I need to do this frequently and at the end of the day I may have millions of observations so I need to find a solution where I can locate the relevant observations in an efficient manner.

I have looked at various collection-types including ones where I can filter the collections with `Predicates` but I have failed to find a solution that would return one value, as opposed to a subset of the collection that fulfills the "<="-condition. I am essentially looking for the SQL equivalent of `SELECT * FROM ol WHERE time <= t LIMIT 1`.

I am sure there is a smart and easy way to solve my problem so I am hoping to be enlightened. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try TreeSet providing a comparator that compares the time. It mantains an ordered set and you can ask for `TreeSet.floor(E)` to find the greatest min (you should provide a dummy Observation with the time you are looking for). You also have headSet and tailSet for ordered subsets.

It has O(log n) time for adding and retrieving. I think is very suitable for your needs.

If you prefer a Map you can use a TreeMap with similar methods.

Comment: Thanks. That certainly did the trick. I went with a Treemap and use `time` as key. Also, I had to tweak the Comparator a bit to allow non-unique times as keys. Thank you.

Comment: Great. But what key are you using? (or you use a comparator that compare the time and "something more"?)

Comment: I am using `time` in String format as Key and implement a Comparator that evaluates the Keys and always returns -1 or +1 even if the Keys are identical to be able to maintain a full set in the TreeMap even though the Keys are not unique. There may be other ways that I could have achieved that(?), but it works which is the most important thing.

Comment: I was worried because I think a non-consistent ordering (I mean: a comparator that can return a<b and b<a depending on how you call it) could give problems to the map/set. If this is the case I propose a simple solution: you need a total order (a != b for every item) so you can compare time first and then coordinates. I understand you won't have equal values for all Observation properties :) If it's not the case, then the observation object could have a private id initialized from a `private static AtomicInteger counter` in this way: `counter.incrementAndGet`. So you always could compare id...

Comment: You are absolutely right. While the solution I created with with TreeMaps and tweaked Comparators appered to give me the observations I was looking for, I do see your point about the lack of reliability. I have reworked the solution with a counter, accordng to your suggestion, that I have added to the observations and then base the Comparator on a mix of time/counter, plus I store the observations in a TreeSet. I am doing some testing now but it seems to work fine from first appearances. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sort your collection (ArrayList will probably work best here) and use [BinarySearch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object%29) which returns an integer index of either a match of the "closest" possible match, ie it returns an...

> index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size(),

Answer (score 4):

Have the `Observation` class implement `Comparable` and use a `TreeSet` to store the objects, which will keep the elements sorted. `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet`, so  you can use `headSet` or `tailSet` to get a view of the set before or after the element you're searching for. Use the `first` or `last` method on the returned set to get the element you're seeking.

If you are stuck with `ArrayList`, but can keep the elements sorted yourself, use `Collections.binarySearch` to search for the element. It returns a positive number if the exact element is found, or a negative number that can be used to determine the closest element. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough to be using Java 6, and the performance overhead of keeping a `SortedSet` is not a big deal for you. Take a look at [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) `ceiling`, `floor`, `higher` and `lower` methods.